# how to debug into Microsoft.Bot.Builder C# project source code?

Tags: c#, botframework

i want to debug into Microsoft.Bot.Builder C# project source code. 
 i download source code from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) . I change my bot project ref to Microsoft.Bot.Builder C# project will cause many errors, like 
 can't find type or namespace name 'IDialog<>' .... 
 thanks for yours help.

Comment: Have you tried restoring the nuget packages?

Comment: hi @Thennarasan, use nuget package's can't debug into Microsoft.Bot.Builder C# project source code use vs.net 2017 .

Comment: No what he means is restoring the nuget packages the github project uses. The code of the BotBuilder is also dependent of some packages. Try to clean and build the solution to restore packages.

Comment: hi @Xeno-D,  i want debug into Microsoft.Bot.Builder.DLL's code with my own bot project together . So, i download source code from github and add to my solution. change my bot project ref to Microsoft.Bot.Builder C# project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove the Nuget reference to Microsoft.Bot.Builder

2) Add the following four projects to your solution:
(downloaded from: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Library )

- Microsoft.Bot.Builder
- Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac
- Microsoft.Bot.Connector
- Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared

3) Add project references to .Builder, .Autofac and .Connector into your bot project.

[image]

You should be able to debug the BotBuilder source now.